# How to use connect from react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm having a little problem with connect(). I thought wrapping all components in Provider is going to work, but turns out it isn't....
So I found that I need to use connect() from react-redux. The problem is i don't know how should I use it. [This site](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) is showing some examples but, i don't have any action creators to put inside connect because I don't use them.......
Can someone give me some advices? I just want to access my store inside components...

Answer (score 8):

In order to use your store in your container you need to do two things

**Firstly** : make use of `mapStateToProps()` .
     As the name suggests, it maps the state variables from your store to the props that you specify

**Secondly** : You need to connect these `props` to your container. This is where `connect()` comes into picture. The object returned by the `mapStateToProps` component is connected to the container. You can import connect from `react-redux` like `import {connect} from 'react-redux';`

**Example**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.containerData}</div>;
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { containerData: state.appData };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Comment: Clear and concise...

Answer (score 2):

You might have better luck with the Redux documentation [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html).

Here's a simple example of how the connect function works:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Item extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div onClick={() => this.props.dispatch( /* some action here */ )}>{this.props.name}</div>;
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { name: state.name };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Item);
```

What happens above is when you export the `Item` component, you're exporting the wrapped, connected component. Wrapping the component will pass in the prop `name` from the app state (it will also pass in the `dispatch` function as a prop.

Comment: I think you need to pass `mapStateToProps` to `connect` instead of `select`. :)

Comment: Oops, thanks! Edited.