# Component not updating when redux store modified

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm using redux thunk to return an API call on an action:

```
export const getActiveCampaigns = () => {
return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const bearer = 'Bearer ' + getState().login.bearer
    return axios.get(API.path + 'campaign/active/?website_id=' + getState().selectedWebsite.selectedWebsite + '&' + API.beaconAPI_client, { headers: { 'Authorization': bearer } })
    .then(function (response) {
        dispatch({
            type: GET_ACTIVE_CAMPAIGNS,
            activeCampaigns: response.data.response
        })
    })
  }
}
```

This works as in it successfully returns a list of campaigns, which I'm rendering into another component using:

```
class ActiveCampaignsDropdown extends Component {
    // usual stuff

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.dispatch(getActiveCampaigns())
    }

    // render function displays campaigns using this.props.activeCampaigns
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        activeCampaigns: state.activeCampaigns.activeCampaigns
    }
}
```

However, note `getState.selectedWebsite.selectedWebsite` on the action. This is set from an action elsewhere in the app, where a user chooses a website from a dropdown list. My reducers look like this:

```
export default function (state = {}, action) {
switch(action.type){
    case SET_SELECTED_WEBSITE:
        return {
            ...state,
            selectedWebsite: action.websiteId
        }
    default:
        return state;
  }
}

export default function (state = {}, action) {
    switch(action.type){
        case GET_ACTIVE_CAMPAIGNS:
        return {
            ...state,
            activeCampaigns: action.activeCampaigns
        }
        default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

My action for setting the selected website:

```
export const setSelectedWebsite = (websiteId) => {
    return {
        type: SET_SELECTED_WEBSITE,
        websiteId
    }
}
```

This is combined with other reducers like so:

```
export default combineReducers({
    login,
    activeWebsites,
    activeCampaigns,
    selectedWebsite  
})
```

**The problem**

The contents of the active campaigns dropdown box works fine on page load - and the state tree does update - but *it doesn't update when the selected website changes*. From what I can see:

1. I am dispatching the action correctly
2. I am updating state, rather than mutating it

I'm quite disappointed that Redux isn't "just working" in this instance, though it is possible I'm overlooking something silly having had only a few hours sleep! Any help appreciated.

Comment: is ur state tree changing ? and it will be better if you can post the component where you are using this state object as well.

Comment: Please show us your component implementation and the part where you connect to the store.

Comment: it's connected by calling props.dispatch and mapStateToProps. The state tree is changing, but only on page load.

Comment: Show me the `GET_ACTIVE_CAMPAIGNS` reducer

Comment: EDIT: added to the code above

Comment: You are not saving the `activeCampaigns`, it should be stored, as state changes, your `activeCampaigns` is always empty

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly how do you mean?

Comment: How sure are you that your state has always a `state.activeCampaigns.activeCampaigns` property? Your default state seems to be an empty object

Comment: @Icepickle certain. I am saving changes in localStorage, so when I reload the page, the campaigns change to match the website Id they were given. The problem is the campaigns don't change immediately.

Comment: Show the `SET_SELECTED_WEBSITE` Action

Comment: It's reducer you added, and its duplicated, show the Action

Comment: make sure `setSelectedWebsite(websiteId)` always has value, console.log it, probably its not getting value

Comment: If I console log it in the action, it gets the websiteId every time...

Comment: Is it because the getActiveCampaigns action is only called on component mounting, and when setSelectedWebsite is called, that is performed away from the campaigns component? If this is the case, I've completely misunderstood what Redux is supposed to do! I assumed that *any change of state* would be reflected, automatically, across the application where appropriate.

Comment: Do you connect your component to the store via redux's `connect()` method?

Comment: Yes. If I am not mistaken, this does that: this.props.dispatch(setSelectedWebsite(e.target.value))

Comment: check if this is `state.activeCampaigns.activeCampaigns` or just `state.activeCampaigns`

Comment: The `connect()` method takes two functions: 'mapStateToProps' and 'mapDispatchToProps.' `connect()` returns a stateless container component whose only function is to provide your 'ActiveCampaignsDropdownComponent' with the desired props from store. The code to do this is as follows: `const ActiveCampaignsDropdownContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ActiveCampaignsDropdownComponent);`. It is this container you need to render.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41021369/how-to-use-connect-from-react-redux for more details

Comment: @sookie I think I follow but please could you provide an answer with a code sample that I can try?

Comment: @MattSaunderts Sure, give me a few minutes

Comment: @sookie I may have resolved this, but it feels a little hacky. In my website dropdown I am calling setSelectedWebsite(website_id). I have discovered that if I also call getActiveCampaigns - this.props.dispatch(getActiveCampaigns()) - here, the campaigns dropdown reloads as it's supposed to. This feels like an anti-pattern - calling an action on an event handler in a different component in order to "force" a state refresh. Thoughts?

Comment: @MattSaunders Yes, forcing a refresh from another component whose responsibility isn't to do that would be bad design. After looking at your code again, I think I know what your problem is. When you switch website, your ActiveCampaignsDropdown doesn't know about it. Because none of its props have changed, there is no update. I'll edit my answer to include a full solution for you. PS: It would also be considered bad practice to provide a component with the `dispatch` function directly. Instead use mapDispatchToProps to provide wrapper functions around your dispatch calls (see my answer below)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In React, components update when one of three things happen:

- Props changed
- State changed
- forceUpdate() is called

In your circumstances, you're looking to update `ActiveCampaignsDropdown` when `state.activeCampaigns` changes in the store. To do this, you must hook up your component so that it receives this value as a prop (and thus force an update when it changes).

This can be done as follows:

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

class ActiveCampaignsDropdown extends React.Component { ... }
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({activeCampaigns: state.activeCampaigns});
const Container = connect(mapStateToProps)(ActiveCampaignsDropdown);

export default Container;
```

The final `Container` component will do all the work of connecting `ActiveCampaignsDropdown` with the desired store state through its props.

Redux's `connect()` also allows us to hook up dispatch functions for modifying data in the store. For instance:

```
// ... component declaration
// ... mapStateToProps

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => 
{
    return {
        getActiveCampaigns: () => dispatch(getActiveCampaigns())
    };
}

const Container = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ActiveCampaignsDropdown);
```

Once the mapping functions are defined, the container component is created, and the container is rendered, `ActiveCampaignsDropdown` will be hooked up correctly. In my example, it will receive 'activeCampaigns' and 'getActiveCampaigns' as props and update accordingly when their values change.

---

**Edit:**

After taking another look at your code, I believe your issue is due to the fact that no condition has been met in order to update `ActiveCampaignsDropdown` when the website has changed. By calling `getActiveCampaigns()` from your WebsiteDropdown (as per your comment), this is forcing `state.activeCampaigns` to change, which successfully updates `ActiveCampaignsDropdown`. As mentioned in one of my comments, 'forcing' this change from a component whose responsibility isn't to do that would be considered bad practice.

A perfectly reasonable solution is for `ActiveCampaignsDropdown` to 'listen' for changes to the current website and update itself accordingly. For this, you need to do two things:

(1) Map website state to the component

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        activeCampaigns: state.activeCampaigns.activeCampaigns, // unsure why structured like this
        selectedWebsite: state.selectedWebsite.selectedWebsite
    }
}
```

(2) Move your dispatch call into componentWillReceiveProps

```
class ActiveCampaignsDropdown extends React.Component
{
    // ...

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)
    {
        if (this.props.selectedWebsite !== nextProps.selectedWebsite)
        {
            this.props.getActiveCampaigns();
        }
    }
}
```

Now every time the selected website changes, a refresh will occur and `componentWillReceiveProps()` will be called (causing `activeCampaigns` to also update). When this update has been applied, another refresh will happen and the rendered dropdown will contain the newly updated campaigns.

**Some minor improvements:**

- If a number of your components rely on the state of the current website (which I imagine is many), then you may consider providing them with it via [`context`](https://medium.com/dailyjs/reacts-%EF%B8%8F-new-context-api-70c9fe01596b).
- Now that your `ActiveCampaignsDropdown` receives 'selectedWebsite' as a prop, you can pass this directly to your action function instead of having it fetch it from state (using `getState()`) - which by the way should also be avoided if at all possible.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. Now if I'm using mapDispatchToProps for all action calls, how can I pass parameters? For example, if this call is in mapDispatchToProps, how would I pass an argument into it: setSelectedCampaign: () => dispatch(setSelectedCampaign()). Hopefully, not using internal state!

Comment: I've resolved this by passing in the value like so: setSelectedCampaign: (campaignId) => dispatch(setSelectedCampaign(campaignId))

Comment: @MattSaunders Yep, you got it